# c & sql - Table not accepting insert statement

Tags: sql, c, db2

So I've been scratching my head over this code for a while now and I can't figure out why my code won't let me.

This is in my create statement:

```
create table account (  number int  not null generated always as identity (start with 1000, increment by 1, no cache), 
        id int      not null, 
        balance int     not null check (balance >=0), 
        type char (1)   not null check (type in ('C', 'S')), 
        status char (1) not null check (status in ('A', 'I')),
        primary key (number));
```

And this is what is in my sqc file.

```
printf ("Please enter your ID: ");
  scanf("%d", &vid);
  printf ("Please enter your Account type (C for checking or S for Saving): ");
  scanf("%s", &vtype);
  printf ("Please enter your initial balance: ");
  scanf("%d", &vbalance);

  exec sql insert into account (id, balance, type, status)
  values (:vid, :vbalance, :vtype, 'A');

  exec sql declare accountid cursor for
  select number
  from account
  group by number order by number desc fetch first 1 rows only;

  exec sql open accountid;

  exec sql fetch accountid into :vnumber;

  exec sql close accountid;

  printf("Your new account ID: %d", vnumber);
```

And it always returns 0 for some reason, rather than 1000:

```
Please enter your ID: 100
Please enter your Account type (C for checking or S for Saving): C
Please enter your initial balance: 100
Your new account ID: 0
```

I've also checked that table afterwards to see that it remains empty, as if the command never ran through or denied the insert command.

EDIT: So I think my main issue is trying to insert into my 'status', 'A'. I've tried to put it into a variable and send that variable into the table, but it returns that variable as null. Since my table doesn't want a null value, it rejected it and therefore didn't create the transaction.

I've manually inserted into P2.Account with test values and it worked, outputting the correct values. So can anyone direct me to a source that can help me input 'A' into the insert without it changing into null? This may be my only issue.

Comment: I am not seeing a commit any where in your code.  I don't know the details of your database API, but it looks like you might be opening an cursor that isn't aware of your current, uncommitted transaction.  When the program ends, the transaction is rolling back your insert.

Comment: @Doug ah, maybe that could be it. I'm still new to c so I really have no idea what commit does nor do I know if it's required for this. XD but thanks for the tip!

Comment: A transaction will always see changes made by that same transaction, regardless of the DBMS in question, and there is no explicit rollback, so the "uncommitted changes" version is probably incorrect. I'd suspect a failing `INSERT` statement -- since you don't seem to do any error checking in your code, you may not know that it fails.

Comment: @mustaccio actually, in my code, where I tried to put in 'A', I tried to check if it actually goes through. Of course it's kinda hard so I tried to put it into a variable and insert it, but what ended up was that it always ended up being null. that might be my issue since my dB doesn't want nulls

Answer (score 0):

When you start a transaction in a database, you have the option of rolling back (undoing) the changes or committing (saving) the changes.  There are multiple reasons for this functionality.  The first would be if you experienced an error while inserting multiple records; the rollback would undo everything so you can fix the error and restart the insert.

Looks like you are missing the statement after your insert:

```
EXEC SQL COMMIT;
```

I am more familiar with Oracle and Pro-C, but IBM has a nice little tutorial on the DB2 site:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/c/s-tbsel-sqc.html

Comment: I tried the commit but didn't solve the problem. I don't think the commit is the thing I need but it helps. Thanks!